# when do we get PORTMAP procedure GETADDR and GETPORT

Tags: rpc, sunrpc

Can someone comment on how and at which level in portmap program version is decided.
Actually in 2 different environments I am getting different Procedure and program version.
in case 1 : I am getting Program version as 2 and procedure GETPORT
in case 2 : I am getting Program version as 4 and procedure GETADDR.

How can I ensure that in every case GETPORT is called not GETADDR.

Answer (score 0):

The small confusion comes from the fact that you use probably the same client that talk to two 'different' services  to **portmap**, exposed as program with `#100000`, version `2` and **rpcbind** service, exposed as program `#100000`, version `4`. To match the correct service the combination of `program` and the `version` is used. Thus, bough can share the same *TPC/UDP* port, but provide different services.

## portmap

Returns *TCP/UDP* **port number** of registered program, like:

`GETPORT {'program': '100003', 'version': 4}` => `2049`

## rpcbind

Returns the **universal addresses** of registered program, like:

`GETADDR {'program': '100003', 'version': 4, 'netid': 'tcp'}` => `0.0.0.0.8.1`

Typical `rpcbind` service support the `portmap` protocol as well.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can ensure program version 2 is used always. As with new library order is changed earlier Program Version 2 was preferred 1st but now program version 4 is requested 1st.

Comment: This depends on the client app.

Comment: How can we achieve that in client app that is what I want to know actually.